# Use Variable Variable as Array Prefix

Tags: php, arrays, variable-variables

Is it possible to use a variable variable as an array prefix? I have a set of arrays with the format `$x_settings`, and I want to output the values of just one depending on which prefix matches a condition.

This is an extremely stripped-down version of much more complex code, so thanks for your indulgence:

```
$current_env = 'local';

$local_settings = array
(
  'debug' => TRUE,
  'cake'  => TRUE,
  'death' => FALSE
);

$environments = array
(
  'local',
  'dev',
  'prod'
);

foreach( $environments as $env )
{
  if( $current_env == $env )
  {
    define('DEBUG', ${$env}_settings['debug']);
    define('CAKE', ${$env}_settings['cake']);
    define('DEATH', ${$env}_settings['death']);

    break;
  }
}
```

As you can see I tried using `${$env}_settings[]` but that gave me a PHP error:

> unexpected '_settings' (T_STRING)

Possible?

Comment: Why can't you just use 2D array?

Comment: `$current_env = $env` is **always** true, as this means "set `$current_env to the value of $env`". Did you mean the conditional operators `==` or `===`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Your loop should look like below:

```
foreach( $environments as $env )
{
  if( $current_env == $env )
  {
    define('DEBUG', ${$env.'_settings'}['debug']);
    define('CAKE',  ${$env.'_settings'}['cake']);
    define('DEATH', ${$env.'_settings'}['death']);
    break;
  }
}
```

Notes:

- I've fixed the typo in your array declaration. You were using just `=` instead of `=>`.
- I've added a `break` inside your loop - otherwise, you'll be trying to re-declare constants and that will cause PHP to output errors
- I've changed `=` to `==`. `=` is the assignment operator. You need to use `==` (loose comparison) or `===` (strict comparison) instead.

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/99112)

Answer (score 1):

Use 2D array for this purpose:

```
$current_env = 'local';

$environment_settings = array(
    'local' => array('debug' = TRUE, 'cake'  = TRUE, 'death' = FALSE),
    'dev' => array('debug' = TRUE, 'cake'  = FALSE, 'death' = FALSE),
    'prod' => array('debug' = TRUE, 'cake'  = TRUE, 'death' = FALSE)
);

if (isset($environment_settings[$current_env])) {
    foreach ($environment_settings[$current_env] as $name => $val)
        define(strtoupper($name), $value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just make a 2-d array...

```
$settings=array(
    "local" => array(
         'cake'=>TRUE,
         'death'=>FALSE
    ),
    "dev" =>array(...etc ...),
    "prod"=>array(...etc ...)
);
```

then:

```
if( $current_env = $env )
{
   define('DEBUG', $settings[$env]['debug']);
   define('CAKE', $settings[$env]['cake']);
   define('DEATH', $settings[$env]['death']);
}
```

(I just typed this in - there may be typos!)

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
$local_settings = array
(
    'debug' => TRUE,
    'cake'  =>TRUE,
    'death' => FALSE
);
```

Make use of the **`=>`** operator instead of **`=`** operator when assigning keys to values

Answer (score 0):

I changed the values to strings just for testing. Try this:

```
$env = 'local';

$local_settings = array
(
  'debug' => 'TRUE',
  'cake'  => 'TRUE',
  'death' => 'FALSE'
);

$setting_selector=$env.'_settings';
echo ${$setting_selector}['debug'];
```